# Showing $f \leq \|f\|_\infty$ almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

We have $\|f\|_\infty = \mathrm{esssup} |f| = \inf\{a \in \mathbb{R}:\mu(|f|>a)=0\}$. I would like to say that that inf is in fact a max, i.e. that $\mu(|f|>\|f\|_\infty)=0$, but I have never seen is stated as a max before, so I question why that is.

Is it true that $\mu(|f|>\|f\|_\infty)=0$? Or is there an example where this fails?

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=Y8COquGJy3IC&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=esssup&source=bl&ots=LRUvX-u2Wc&sig=gzuihBvLcmhdKH8z5aOf6CPeewk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o7MpUdPoIaHH0wHJkYDQCQ&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=esssup&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct and that is because you are taking the infimum of all 'upper bounds' of $|f|$ in terms of measure (i.e., $\mu(|f|>a)>0$ for every $a<\Vert f\Vert_\infty$).

The problem with saying max or even supremum is that these don't take into account how *often* the function assumes these values. On the extended real line, we can always define a function to be $\infty$ on a set of measure zero and we won't have changed the value of an integral, even though it may assume the value $\infty$ infinitely many times (for example, on $\Bbb Q$).